# Changing React Leaflet Circle color with Leaflet Timedimension Plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm building a React app that has a Leaflet map and integrates the Leaflet Timedimension Plugin.
The goal is to have a map that has some Circles, those changes radius and color whenever the Timedimension plugin loads a new time.

I've successfully created a map that has some Circles that changes based on the Timedimension plugin times (currentTimeIndex changes whenever a new time is loaded), but the colour wouldn't change.
The following code it's my approach to the problem:

```js
      data.map((region) =>
        region.items.map((market) => (
          <Circle
            center={[market.lat, market.lon]}
            radius={values[currentTimeIndex]}
            pane='markets'
            key={market.id}
            color={colors[currentTimeIndex]}
          />
        )),
      )
```

Is possible to change the color of the Circle without having to remove and re-add them?

I'll leave here the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cerf-yfbj9?file=/src/Leaflet.js) with the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For weird reasons I cannot really explain, it seems like `colors` does not update, while `pathOptions` seems to work as intended.

I've slightly updated your codesandbox which seems to produce the desired result, the following were changed:

- I have moved `colors` out of the Leaflet component since it's actually a constant.
- I have added a `useMemo` hook to get the current color according to the currentTimeIndex.
- I have changed `color` with `pathOptions`, which is the real fix you need to do.

Side note: I'm not sure how you want to style the circle itself. In case you want to use both fill and stroke, use `fill` and `color` in `pathOptions`, you can find documentation about that in the typings: https://definitelytyped.org/docs/leaflet--leaflet/interfaces/l.pathoptions.html

Relevant code:

```js
const colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "black", "purple", "gray"];
const Leaflet = () => {
  const map = useMap();
  const [currentTimeIndex, setCurrentTimeIndex] = useState(0);
  const values = [5, 15, 25, 5, 15, 25, 5];

  map.timeDimension.on("timeloading", (data) => {
    console.log(data.target._currentTimeIndex);
    setCurrentTimeIndex(data.target._currentTimeIndex);
  });

  const currentColor = useMemo(() => colors[currentTimeIndex], [
    currentTimeIndex
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Pane name="markets" />
      <TileLayer url={"https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"} />
      {SenegalData.map((region) =>
        region.items.map((market) => (
          <Circle
            center={[market.lat, market.lon]}
            radius={values[currentTimeIndex] * 1000}
            pane="markets"
            key={market.id}
            pathOptions={{
              color: currentColor
            }}
          />
        ))
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Step 0 (color red):
[image: step 0]

Step 1 (color green):
[image: step 1]

Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-dew-x11s1?file=/src/Leaflet.js

Comment: This works! Only one question, why you used the `useMemo` hook? Isn't this used only for expensive calculations?

Comment: @FabrizioPaoloPetrelli whenever I need to bind something to a component that relies on something else (like an array property or so) I usually use `useMemo`. In this case specifically it's likely irrelevant, although the best practice in my opinion would be to memoize the entire `pathOptions` since it's identical for each record of the collection.